How to copy files from my local computer to my BeagleBoneBlack using remote file explorer on Visual Studio?
I am trying to copy a folder from my local windows machine that I have connected to a BeagleBoneBlack remotely. However, I can't copy my folders from my local machine to the remote device. There is a warning which I see on my screen

and after following the link to fix them, I ran the commands on my BBB successfully -
sudo apt-get install openssh-server g++ gdb make ninja-build rsync zip

sudo service ssh start

But I still do not see that warning go away and am not able to remotely copy files to it. I have verified that my connection exists. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.
